# PHP Fatal error: Declaration of ...MySQLServer::insert() must be compatible with ...Server::insert()

Tags: php, ооп

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of ...MySQLServer::insert() must be compatible with ...Server::insert() in /home/lfLvpx/prog.php on line 102

Почему возникает эта ошибка, и как ее поправить?

```
abstract class Server
{
public function __construct($token)
{
    if ($token !== $_POST['crm_token']) {
        http_response_code(401);
    } else {
        $this->accept();
    }
}

abstract protected function insert();

...
}

class MySQLServer extends Server
{
protected function insert(mysqli $link, $table, array $required)
{
    $fields     = "`".implode("`, `", $required)."`";
    $fields_num = count( $required );
    $questions  = str_repeat( "?,", $fields_num - 1 ) . "?";
    $query      = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($questions)";

    $data = [];
    foreach( $required as $field ){ 
        $data[] = $_POST[$field];
    }

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query );

    $types = str_repeat('s', $fields_num );
    $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$data );
    $stmt->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: говорят же, функция должна быть такая же как  в Server. У вас такая же? Посмотрите. Сигнатура.

Comment: А как сигнатуру сделать любой?

Comment: написать еще один метод с другим названием...

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать вариант различных вставок с переменным числом аргументов. Для этого тот метод и абстрактный :)

Comment: для переменного числа аргументов в 5.6 придумали http://php.net/manual/ru/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics ......до него обходились `func_get_args` ....а  переопределяющий метод должен быть с соответсвующей абстрактному методу сигнатурой...... если так надо - делайте несколько абстрактных методов с разной сигнатурой)

Comment: единственное исключение по сигнатуре, если в дочернем классе в методе объявлены необязательные параметры например родитель `abstract protected function prefixName($name);` и ребенок `public function prefixName($name, $separator = ".")`.....но что-то мне подсказывает они у вас все обязательные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант для PHP 5.6+

```
<?php
abstract class Server
{
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        //...
    }

    abstract public function insert(...$params);
}

class MySQLServer extends Server
{
    public function insert(...$params)
    {
        print_r($params);
    }
}

$server = new MySQLServer();
$server->insert(1,2,3);

/**
Вывод в консоли:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)

**/
```

Правда, я не вижу никакой пользы в ООП, если в insert необходимо передавать объект подключения к бд. Вся суть ООП раскроется, если объект будет хранить объекты подключения внутри себя, а наружу отдавать стандартизированные методы. Для реализации чего-то кроме MySQLServer понадобится PDO.

Comment: А можно ...$params передать первым аргументом? Типа: `insert(...$params, array $required)`

Comment: Нет, ...$params всегда идет последним. К тому же, придется $required описать в абстрактной функции, что может наложить ограничения.